# Django: Display value other than form entry in formset

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I have a formset that I can pass in a set of forms. I don't want the user to be able to change the profile associated with the specific form and I am having trouble doing this.

`{{form.profile}}` will display a drop down menu with the user's email. `{{form.profile.value}}` will display the profile's id (it is a foreign key to another model). In this case it'll display the number 9. I tried creating a function in the model called `get_name`, but then `{{form.profile.get_name}}` doesn't bring anything back.

What's the right way to display something other than the form item or value when using a formset?

HTML

```
   {% for form in invoiceupdate_form.forms %}
        <tr><td>{{ form.profile }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.start_date.value }}</td>
```

Comment: try decorating the get_name function with @property, something like this :

`@property`
`def get_name(self, *args):`
    `"""Your logic here"""`

Comment: post both the models to clarify your question.

Comment: It seems you're note returning anything from `get_name` method.